# Unable to use matplotlib functions in my program

Tags: python, matplotlib, anaconda

I'm running an Anaconda installation in windows 10 (conda version 4.3.8)

This is the code I'm trying to run in the python command line:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
x = [1,2,3,4]
y = [5,6,7,8]
plt.figure(1)
plt.plot(x,y)
```

The last line throws the following error:

```
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py:971: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The is_string_like function was deprecated in version 2.1.
if is_string_like(family):
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\font_manager.py:697: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The is_string_like function was deprecated in version 2.1.
if is_string_like(family):
C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\text.py:218: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning: The is_string_like function was deprecated in version 2.1.
elif is_string_like(fontproperties):
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 3307, in plot
  ax = gca()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 950, in gca
  return gcf().gca(**kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1368, in gca
  return self.add_subplot(1, 1, 1, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\figure.py", line 1020, in add_subplot
  a = subplot_class_factory(projection_class)(self, *args, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_subplots.py", line 73, in __init__
  self._axes_class.__init__(self, fig, self.figbox, **kwargs)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 529, in __init__
  self._init_axis()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes\_base.py", line 622, in _init_axis
  self.xaxis = maxis.XAxis(self)
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 676, in __init__
  self.cla()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 760, in cla
  self.reset_ticks()
File "C:\ProgramData\Anaconda3\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axis.py", line 771, in reset_ticks
  cbook.popall(self.majorTicks)
AttributeError: module 'matplotlib.cbook' has no attribute 'popall'
```

I'm running this in the root environment Also here is part of the output of the `conda list`

[image]

Are multiple versions of matplotlib in root causing this? How do I resolve this?

Comment: What method did you use to install multiple versions of `matplotlib` within your Anaconda environment? (Usually Anaconda will either upgrade or downgrade the package version depending on which order the different versions are installed.)

Comment: This post: [Matplotlib AttributeError: 'module' object has no attribute 'popall'](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44155564/matplotlib-attributeerror-module-object-has-no-attribute-popall) seems to suggest that having multiple versions of `matplotlib` may possibly cause issues. Although, the configuration they were using is different to yours, it could well be the case that the cause of your issue is similar.

Answer (score 4):

While attempting to use matplotlib.pyplot with the latest version of matplotlib (updated through the Anaconda distribution) I got a very similar error. The error appears to be between the root python version and the Anaconda distribution as the following solves the problem:

- Uninstall matplotlib using pip: "pip uninstall matplotlib"
- Uninstall matplotlib using conda: "conda uninstall matplotlib"
- Install matplotlib using conda: "conda install matplotlib"

Multiple versions of matplotlib does appear to be the issue. This was inferred from the following information (provided in the form of screenshots):

[conda uninstall matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/DYuNc.png)

[pip uninstall matplotlib](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J7igq.png)

Note the matplotlib versions mentioned in the two screenshots. Hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

It's also caused by a version mismatch between networkx and matplotlib. Just uninstall all versions of matplotlib and networkx:

```
sudo pip3 uninstall networkx
sudo pip3 uninstall matplotlib
python3 -mpip uninstall matplotlib
sudo conda uninstall matplotlib
```

If you've installed networkx via other sources like mpip or conda, uninstall those too.

Then install both of them:

```
sudo pip3 install networkx
sudo pip3 install matplotlib
```

Now the program will work.