# Strange error when attempting to import matplotlib

Tags: python

When attempting to import matplotlib, I'm getting the following error:

"ImportError: cannot import name 'is_string_like"

I'm a little confused as to what's happeningas this was working during a previous Ipython session.  Not sure what would be helpful to provide, but I can definitely provide more detail.  I'm working in a jupyter notebook, but this is also happening outside of the notebook.

Comment: have you tried restarting the kernel? Sometimes, weird errors happen when you cancel a cell while a module is loading.

Comment: Just restarted the kernel and still getting the same error.

Comment: Are you importing anything else? How did you install matplotlib?

Comment: pandas and numpy and both were successfully imported.  I installed matplotlib via anaconda.

Comment: any ideas here?

Comment: Did you see and follow advice here? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47571689/unable-to-use-matplotlib-functions-in-my-program